# Umbraco rewriting URL based on old page

Tags: umbraco

I just recently started working on a project that involves Umbraco. So, I am no expert on it (not even close). Please help.

The issue is, we had a page on our site that was example.com/careers.aspx. This page had the old content.

We have now redesigned it and moved the cotent "INTO" careers "folder". So, now it should work as example.com/careers/en/home.aspx.

However, when we go to that URL, it rewrites it as example.com/careers.aspx/en/home.aspx.

I  looked for any rewrite config files but there are no rules (in the file; not sure about DB).

can someone please help? I am not sure what is happening here.

For additional information, when I look at "Properties" for /careers/en/home page then it shows "Link to Document" as "/careers/en/home.aspx".

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you are using Umbraco v4? In the web.config for a Umbraco v4 there is a `umbracoReservedUrls` appSetting key. You could add your path in here and Umbraco will essentially ignore rewriting it when it is requested.

The rewrite configuration is actually in config/UrlRewriting.config and this will allow you to control custom rewrites.

Answer (score 0):

In the web.config you can created rewrite rules for the required pages.

In the < system.webServer> section create a < rewrite> < rules> section and then add  for each page as required.

Would be something like this...

```
<rewrite>
   <rules>

    <rule name="RewriteCareers" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="careers.aspx" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="careers.aspx/en/home.aspx" />
    </rule>

   </rules>
</rewrite>
```